# Send data to Zabbix via TCPIP sockets

Tags: sockets, zabbix, algol

I am trying to send data directly from an Aseries environment to the zabbix server, so I want to create an algol program for sending the data via tcpip sockets.
Do you know if it is possible in zabbix to recive information via sockets ?.
If it is possible, do you know how can i configure it?

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Zabbix sender protocol](http://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/protocols/zabbix_sender/2.0) in (algol) app - it's simple application protocol based on TCP/IP. Some examples implemented by Zabbix community for reference https://monitoringartist.github.io/zabbix-searcher/#sender

And then you need to create [Zabbix item of trapper type](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) to accept data received by sender protocol.